# Integrating postgres to django

Tags: java, python, django, postgresql

im trying to install `psycopg2` to use postgres on my django app. Seems like the first step is to run the

```
sudo apt install python3-dev libpq-dev
```

, but when i do it hits me with this funky error -

```
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)
```

I'm confused as to why its showing me a java error when i'm installing `python-dev`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: use docker - you can pick pieces out of my article that are relevant https://python.plainenglish.io/django-start-building-an-api-in-8-minutes-part-1-6e901dcf8fcd?gi=6ba81e74d676

Answer (score 0):

Install [pip](https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/) by typing:

```
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip
```

It is often a good idea to use [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) when doing projects, otherwise packages are installed system wide.
Type in the following to start a virtual environment in your project directory:

```
python3 -m pip install --user virtualenv
python3 -m venv .
```

Afterwards, this command should install `psycopg2`

```
pip install psycopg2-binary==2.8.4
```